# How to import 3rd party module to python if its name is taken?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0

I want to use this class: [google-mail-oauth2-tools](https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough) but if i'll do something like `import oauth2` the imported class would be [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) which is deprected and doesn't support oauth2 )even though the name is oauth2)
How can I use google module ? do I need to install it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the docs you linked](https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough), it looks like the Google Mail `oauth2` module is meant to be downloaded and used in-place.

You can, of course, install it… but you can't have two (top-level) modules installed with the same name, so you'd have to uninstall `python-oauth2` first.

But if you just use it in-place, in Python 2.7, you can have an `oauth2.py` in one directory and one in the stdlib. Whichever one you import first will "win"; any subsequent attempts to `import oauth2` will get the first one.

To force it to import the right one (in a way that will also work for older Python 2.x and for Python 3.x), you may want to use the [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module to give it the path explicitly.

For example, if you plan to put `oauth2.py` right alongside the script that imports it, instead of just `import oauth2`, do:

```
script_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
f, path, desc = imp.find_module('oauth2', [script_path])
oauth2 = imp.load_module('oauth2', f, path, desc)
```

… although in some situations, you can get away with cheating by assuming the current working directory is the script directory, and/or by permanently munging `sys.path`, etc., so you can simplify it in various different ways—ultimately, if it's safe, just this:

```
sys.path = ['.'] + sys.path
import oauth2
```

Still, I would consider doing one of the following for safety (and readability):

- Uninstall `python-oauth2`.
- Rename the downloaded `oauth2.py` to something else, like `google_oauth2.py`, and then `import google_oauth2`.
- Put the downloaded `oauth2.py` into a package, so you can, e.g., `import googletools.oauth2`.